# How to reference vtk dll files from my project in visual studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vtk

How to reference vtk dll files from my project in visual studio 2010?

I have vc++ project, but when I start debugging I have error "missing dll"...

Comment: I usually use the simple, but perhaps not the most efficient, approach of copying the vtk dlls to the directory with my executable.

Comment: For vtk, ITK and GDCM I avoid this issue by building these as static libraries. For Qt I created a CMake script that generates a custom target to copy the Qt dlls into my Release, Debug and RelWithDebInfo folders. This script makes use of the cmake QT_* variables to get the location of the dlls.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to load Visual Studio with the DLL directories in your path.

For example: a batch file to run Visual studio with commands such as:

```
set PATH=C:/MyDirectory/VTK/bin/Debug;%PATH%
```

`START %~dp0\MySolution.sln`

will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use cmake to build your project from source. You should check out this tutorial. It could be helpful for you.

[Setup VTK in Visual Studio](https://youtu.be/IgvbhyDh8r0?list=PLCy_sCre7VyDhVEozGPt5h_wQzkJXVGU1)

Answer (score 0):

The error comes because VS does not find the DLL libraries.

The simple way to fix it is (VS 2017):

1) Add the VTK dll's to the system path:

a) Open the system environment variables

[image]

b) System Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables
[image]

c) System Variables -> Select Path -> Edit
[image]

d) Add path to VTK Dlls[image]
e) Press ok and close and open VS, it should not complain now about not finding the VTK DLLs (If it does not work try restarting the computer to update the environement system variables, it should not be necessary).

2) The next method did not work for me (ref: https://github.com/esmitt/FirstVTK)

a) You need to create a global variable pointing to the VTK DLLs. In the Environment Variables window (step 1C) select new and create a new variable pointing to the DLLs. I have VTK_DIR = "C:\Program Files (x86)\VTK\bin".

[image]

b) In Visual Studio, Project-Properties

[image]
c) Configuration properties -> Debugging -> Environment --> PATH=%PATH%;%VTK_DIR%
[image]

d) Press Apply -> Ok

e) Let's hope it will work for you.